# Phalcon datetime in model query error

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I am trying to execute a query like this:

`Select * from table where created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` in phalcon model query form. But i keep getting the following error:

> Syntax error, unexpected token INTEGER(1), near to ' DAY)',

By query building is like below

```
$donations = Donations::query()
        ->where('created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
        ->execute();
```

The above code gives me that error. Now i have tried like below

```
$donations = Donations::query()
        ->where('created_at > :holder:')
        ->bind(["holder" => 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'])
        ->execute();
```

Although this binding does not give me an error, it gives me a 0 result but i have a few rows inserted into the table to check this and when i execute the query in phpmyadmin it works correctly, So i assumed there might be a datetime mix up in the phalcon library setup of mine but when i changed from `1 DAY` to `1 MONTH` there is still not result. Can someone guide me on this.

Comment: I haven't used the phalcon framework but based on others I think it will be something to do with the fact the where function needs to know that it's native sql functionality. Try something like  ->where(new RawValue('created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INTERVAL`, `DATE_SUB`, `NOW()` and other similar are MySQL only features and are not supported by PHQL.

You have two options:

1) Rewrite your `WHERE` condition by using PHP date:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 DAY')); // Modify according to your date format
$donations = Donations::query()
    ->where('created_at > :holder:')
    ->bind(["holder" => $date)
    ->execute();
```

2) Extend MySQL with a dialect class:

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host"         => $config->database->host,
        "username"     => $config->database->username,
        "password"     => $config->database->password,
        "dbname"       => $config->database->name,
        "dialectClass" => '\Phalcon\Db\Dialect\MysqlExtended'
    ));
});
```

More info in the following links:

**How to extend:** https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1748/date-sub-interval-mysql#C6291

**The dialect class itself:** https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/blob/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Dialect/MysqlExtended.php

Comment: I'll stick to using the php date function. Cheers!